# How to stop my repo from cloning into new folder and clone into direct folder instead

Tags: git

I have a template I created but when cloning into the Django project folder it creates a subproject folder. I want it to just clone the subfolders and files when cloning the repo. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about Git or am I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple:

`git clone YOUR_REPO_URL .`

Comment: This will only work if the current directory is empty, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check out to a directory that isn't empty, you can do it like this:

```sh
cd my_django_project
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/MyGitHubUser/my-django-project.git
git fetch
git checkout -t origin/master
```

Good luck!